# How to remove the double quotes from the array object without change the array?

Tags: reactjs

Using ReactJS, how can I remove the double quotes from each array object without changing the array?

For example, given:

```
0: Array(2)
     0: "23.94107556246209"
     1: "54.00604248046876"
1: Array(2)
     0: "24.457150524185852"
     1: "55.09094238281251"
2: Array(2)
     0: "23.90843786128921"
     1: "55.18157958984375"
```

my desired output is:

```
0: Array(2)
     0: 23.94107556246209
     1: 54.00604248046876
1: Array(2)
     0: 24.457150524185852
     1: 55.09094238281251
2: Array(2)
     0: 23.90843786128921
     1: 55.18157958984375
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const array = [["23.94107556246209", "54.00604248046876"], ["24.457150524185852","55.09094238281251"]]

const newArray = array.map(item => {
return item.map(val => Number(val))
})
```

use Number() to format your string value